# How to differentiate http and xmlrpc ports in odoo?

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

It's easy to change default 8069 port in odoo. How can I differentiate xmlrpc port from basic http-protocol port so that I can prevent xmlrpc calls (external) easily with firewall.

Comment: Now I got you, it is not defaulty available in odoo.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need 2 Odoo instances sharing the filestore and database. One for HTTP client, one for XML-RPC access. You can then make your reverse proxy block all requests to `/web` for the XML-RPC instance.

[XML-RPC](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) uses `/xmlrpc` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You could also modify controllers. You could provide a new system parameter to record the internal subnet you are running on. In the main controller handling incoming requests you could parse the headers and determine the origin of the request and simply reject it if it does not match your internal subnet. Making internal rpc calls available and rejecting them from external sources.